# HTML Log In form connection to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I am facing problems connecting my HTML form to database. I am very new at this. Please do help me.
This is the HTML Login form code
logout.html

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="submit1()" action="connectivity-sign-up.php" method="POST" >
   <div id="errorBox"></div>
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="First Name"  class="input_name" >
    <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="input_name" >

  </div>
  <div id="email_form">
    <input type="text" name="Email" value=""  placeholder="Your Email" class="input_email">
  </div>
  <div id="Re_email_form">
    <input type="text" name="enterEmail" value=""  placeholder="Re-enter Email" class="input_Re_email">
  </div>
  <div id="password_form">
    <input type="password" name="Password" value=""  placeholder="New Password" class="input_password">
  </div>
  <!--birthday details start-->
  <div>
    <h3 class="birthday_title">Birthday</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="birthday_month" >
      <option value="" selected >Month</option>
      <option value="1">Jan</option>
      <option value="2">Feb</option>
      <option value="3">Mar</option>
      <option value="4">Apr</option>
      <option value="5">May</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="birthday_day" >
      <option value="" selected>Day</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="birthday_year">
      <option value="" selected>Year</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2012">2012</option>
      <option value="2011">2011</option>
      <option value="2010">2010</option>
      <option value="2009">2009</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!--birthday details ends-->
  <div id="radio_button">
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
    <label >Female</label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
    <label >Male</label>
  </div>
   <div>
    <p id="sign_user" onClick="Submit()" value= "Submit" >Sign Up </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
 </form>
```

The Submit1() function is the validate function. When I click Submit it should first validate and then send the data to the form. Now the validate function works properly but how do I call it such that it will send the data once validated.And here is the PHP connectivity part
File name : connectivity-sign-up.php

```
    <?php define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'customerdb'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
function Signin() 
{ 
 $fname = $_POST['Name']; 
 $lname = $_POST['LastName']; 
 $email = $_POST['Email']; 
 $password = $_POST['Password']; 
 $query = "INSERT INTO custtable (fname,lname,email,password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email','$password')"; 
 $data = mysql_query ($query)or  die(mysql_error()); 
 if($data) 
  { 
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; 
  } 
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user click submit button call **`Signin()`** function.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    Signin();
}
```

-

```
<?php define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'customerdb');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    Signin();
}

function Signin()
{
    $fname = $_POST['Name'];
    $lname = $_POST['LastName'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO custtable (fname,lname,email,password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email','$password')";
    $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($data) {
        echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
    }
}

?>
```

Update html : `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`

```
    <!--birthday details ends-->
    <div id="radio_button">
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
        <label>Female</label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
        <label>Male</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="sign_user" onClick="Submit()" value="Submit">Sign Up </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Best answer posted, but might I recommend amending it to use MySQLi and `MySQLi::real_escape_string()`. MySQL is depreciated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. The content should be sanitized using `MySQLi::real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the method declaration for `Signin()` and just have the entire page as a script, then the logic you have in the function will execute. This would result in the following file:

```
<?php define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
  define('DB_NAME', 'customerdb'); 
  define('DB_USER','root'); 
  define('DB_PASSWORD','');

  $con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
  $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 

  $fname = $_POST['Name']; 
  $lname = $_POST['LastName']; 
  $email = $_POST['Email']; 
  $password = $_POST['Password']; 

  $query = "INSERT INTO custtable (fname,lname,email,password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email','$password')"; 
  $data = mysql_query ($query)or  die(mysql_error()); 

  if($data) 
  { 
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; 
  } 
?>
```

Another alternative is to actually call the function somewhere in the page like so:

`Signin()`

Comment: As in , I should add the connectivity-sign-up.php file to the logout.HTML or what? Sorry, I am quite new and thus need slight more description . Would be very grateful if you do that, thanks.

Comment: No worries :-) I just updated the answer to include what it looks like if you don't end up having a `Signin()` function. See Jeff's answer below for what it looks like when you call `Signin()`

Answer (score 1):

When click Sign Up, the information will be send to connectivity-sign-up.php, and execute the code in connectivity-sign-up.php. And Signin() is not invoked, there is just a declare.

```
<?php define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'customerdb'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
function Signin() 
{ 
 $fname = $_POST['Name']; 
 $lname = $_POST['LastName']; 
 $email = $_POST['Email']; 
 $password = $_POST['Password']; 
 $query = "INSERT INTO custtable (fname,lname,email,password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email','$password')"; 
 $data = mysql_query ($query)or  die(mysql_error()); 
 if($data) 
  { 
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; 
  } 
}
//invoke Signin
Signin();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better option would be executing the `Signin()` function somewhere in the page.And you would need to add a connetion between the `connectivity-sign-up.php` and `logout.html` file